# nginx ingress content based routing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have installed the nginx ingress controller along with its CRDs (virtual servers, routes ...etc.) as per the [installation guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/). Moreover I already run the  [advanced routing example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v2.0.3/examples-of-custom-resources/advanced-routing)  successfully. Now I am trying to enhance this example by making the routing to be based on the request body ($request_body). but unfortunately it is not working for me. Below is the path section I have appended to the the [cafe-virtual-server.yaml](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v2.0.3/examples-of-custom-resources/advanced-routing/cafe-virtual-server.yaml).

Note: /api/test api is available

```
  - path: /mytest
    matches:
      - conditions:
        - variable: $request_body
          value: ~*abc*
        action:
          proxy:
            upstream: tea-post
            rewritePath: /api/test
    action:
      pass: coffee-v1
```

**Update 1 :**
I have enabled the debug mode and updated the log-format to print the $request & $request_body but these variables printed as empty, PFB.

*curl command :*

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain"  -d 'abc' -k -vvv https://test.company.com/testx
```

*config map log-format property update:*

> log-format: upstreaminfo $remote_addr xx-xx $remote_user
> [$time_local]\n
> $request $request_body $status $body_bytes_sent \n
> $http_referer $http_user_agent \n

*Logs output :*

2021/12/29 05:22:56 [debug] 90#90: *928 http log handler
upstreaminfo 10.54.192.1 xx-xx - [29/Dec/2021:05:22:56 +0000]
POST /testx HTTP/1.1 - 404 108
- curl/7.29.0

Comment: This part of ingress looks correct. Please check the [value](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#condition) so it's correct and look into logs what exactly happens when you make a request.

Comment: Thanks @moonkotte, I have updated the question (Update 1) for the logs after testing.

Comment: So, I tested this. 1st - your configmap is applied based on `xx-xx` which you added, it doesn't write body when 404 is returned. 2nd - 404. Something is wrong with virtual service, check paths and upstreams. 3rd - I was able to set it up with `$request_method` and it worked well - part of the logs `"POST /test HTTP/1.1" 405 157 test1234 "-"  "curl/7.58.0"` - even `$request_body` is presented, but it doesn't work when I try to replicate your case. That said, I suggest to raise the issue in [their github project](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress), so they can explain what and why.

Comment: See [the 2nd example](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#match) - this one works just fine. With `$request_body` set it doesn't. All requests are sent to the main upstream WITHOUT logging $request_body, it becomes empty. It can be something easy, as suggested, the fastest way is to ask developers about it.

Comment: Yes I tried with the cookie and the method type it works. the only issue with the body. Fine I will raise the same in their github project. Thanks ..